# eleventy: render a style in a noscript tag in the head

Tags: html, css, nunjucks, noscript, eleventy

I've got a nunjucks template in `_include/partials/head-content.njk` that ends with these three lines.

```html
<noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/_assets/noscript.css' | asset | url }}"/>
</noscript>
```

This is rendering as the following HTML in my pages:

```html
<noscript>
  &#x3C;link rel="stylesheet" href="/_site-dev/_merged_assets/noscript.css"/>
</noscript>
```

How can I get Eleventy to respect this `<noscript>` tag's contents?

My workaround:

```js
eleventyConfig.addTransform('fix-noscript-style', content =>
  content.replace(`<noscript>&#x3C;link`, '<noscript><link'));
```

Comment: Does it escape `<link>` without `href` attribute?

Comment: What level of indentation is that `<link` at? if it is too far indented it could be parsing it as a md code block

Comment: Can you please share your `.eleventy.js`?

Comment: I'm using 'rocket' eleventy meta framework (currently in pre-release)